# Assigning autonumber to HTML form entry

Tags: php, html, csv, autonumber

I have searched everywhere, but nothing I find seems to help solve this. I have a html web form (in a PHP document) that writes data to a CSV file, and below the form is a table that filters the CSV data back in based on a key word. I have no problems with my existing code for that part. However, I need to have an auto-number function that assigns a number to each form. I need help on even where to start. I'm still relatively new to coding, so any help would be great. 
**Edit**: Here is the code I use to write my data to the csv file.

```
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $fs = fopen("fixturerequests.csv","a");
    fwrite($fs,$varFixNum . ", " . $varRequester . ", " . $varDept . ", " . $varSupervisor . ", " . $varDesc . ", " . $varParts . ", " . $varWC . ", " . $varAddinfo . ", " . $varDateReq . ", " . $varDateNeed . ", " .$varStatus . "\n");
    fclose($fs);

    header("Location: successfullysubmitted.php");
    exit;
}
```

Any guidance would be excellent. Thank you.

Comment: where is the code that creates the form?If every form is a row in a csv file all you have to do is count how many rows the csv file has.

Comment: Of course if rows are deleted and you want the number of the forms to act as an id and remain constant then you should just assign another field in your csv like 'form_id' and every time you want to add a form just get the last record from the csv get the form_id of this record and add 1 to it.It all depends on what you want.If you give more info we will be able to help you more

Comment: @GeorgePant The second suggestion you had sounds like the best option - Pulling the previous number and adding one. That's what I started attempting in the code above, but as I mentioned before I'm fairly new to coding. Yes, each response to a question on the form is a new row. Would you like me to edit my response to include that code? Or is it not relevant?

Comment: Yes that would help

Comment: @GeorgePant I edited my original post. The code you posted below doesn't seem to work. I figure the problem is simply that I need to add it to my code that writes to the csv file. However, what would I use to reference your code? Would it just be $data ?

Comment: Like i say in my answer "suppose in your csv file the first field is the form id number you want"....

Comment: I edited my answer based on the code you provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function

```
function next_available_form_id(){

    $rows = file('fixturerequests.csv');  //put our csv file into an array

    if(empty($rows)) return 1;            //if our csv is empty we start from 1

    $data = str_getcsv(array_pop($rows)); //array_pop gets the last row

    return $data[0]+1;            //we get first field and add 1 to it
                                  //Just use the field where you store the form number 
                                  //e.g if you store the form number in the  
                                  //4th field replace $data[0] with $data[3]

}
```

Based on the code you provided you can use the function I provided to get the next form_id before storing it in the csv file.Just make this modification to your code after opening the csv file :

```
$fs = fopen("fixturerequests.csv","a");
$form_id=next_available_form_id();  //ADD THIS to get the next available id

//And insert $form_id as the first field in your csv file  
fwrite($form_id,$fs,$varFixNum . ", " . $varRequester . ", " . $varDept . ", " . $varSupervisor . ", " . $varDesc . ", " . $varParts . ", " . $varWC . ", " . $varAddinfo . ", " . $varDateReq . ", " . $varDateNeed . ", " .$varStatus . "\n");
```

**Notice:**
Of course since the csv you have now does not have form_id as the first field you should either create your csv file from scratch or add form numbers in your existing records.In the example I use awk to do that:

```
  awk '{printf "%d,%s\n", NR, $0}' < fixturerequests.csv
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help with this!

Comment: Happy my answer helped you